# Post Build events in .net

Tags: .net, post-build-event

I want to write post build event in one project of class library so that dll will be copied to some spacific directory after project build.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far and what happened?  Have you read [How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)?

Comment: have you tried do google it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: i dont know how to write it. but i want to copy .net dll to one specific folder.

Comment: Google "xcopy", take the first hit.

Comment: -1, If you actually took the time to search for a solution, you'd find that it is very trivial and the same answer that anyone else would give you here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Project Properties and select 'Build Events' tab. You will get the options.

BTW, what is the VS version?